# Qt: Reason for the calling of closeEvent(...)

Tags: qt

On Mac when you click the widget's red "close" button, your QWidget will receive a "closeEvent" call.

However, if you click "cmd-Q" on your keyboard to quit the application, your open QWidget will also receive a "closeEvent".

at "closeEvent" time, is there a way to figure out why it's being called? because the user closed that particular window, or because the user his just tried quitting the application altogether?

or in other words, will the QCoreApplication/QAppliction object have some clue it it, some flag indicating it's in a "I'm about to close the App" mode that I can inspect during the closeEvent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#advanced-signals-and-slots-usage

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qevent.html#spontaneous

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcloseevent-members.html

If you put `void closeEvent()` in a <strike>`public slots:`</strike> `protected:`

<strike>You can query the objectName of the sender of the `closeEvent()`.</strike>

```
qDebug() << QObject::sender()->objectName();
```

Otherwise

You can filter based on the `spontaneous()` member of `QCloseEvent`.

```
qDebug() << closeEvent->spontaneous();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Querying the sender isn't valid because `closeEvent()` is an event, not a slot; for that reason, `QObject::sender()` is null, thus calling `QObject::sender()->objectName()` will crash the program.

Comment: I used to put `closeEvent()` and `showEvent()` as slots in my subclassed objects... now I put them just as `protected:` instead.